# Offset key WORD for cipher in Python

Tags: python

So I am half way through a Computing GCSE controlled assessment at school.

I have completed task one of my controlled assessment which was to create a Caeser Cipher which encrypts a message by offsetting each letter in the message by a key number which the user must enter.

Task two  is to do the same, but using a key WORD.

This means that the keyword string must be multiplied until it is the same length as the message which the user enters(from part one). For example:

keyword=gcse

usersmessage= Hello, my name is Jake

The keyword must be multiplied so it looks something like this compared to the message:

**gcsegcsegcsegcsegcsegc**

**Hello, my name is Jake**

Now the above message and key word are the same length (22 characters, although they don't look it)

Next, each ascii value of each character must be added together, meaning the first letter of each string is added together, then the second, then third etc..

Until each letter of the message now has a new value, once the program has carried out this process it will need to print the **encrypted** message onto the screen for the user to see. Can anybody help with this? It's hard to explain here but hopefully somebody will know what I'm on about :)
The main issue I am having is that I cannot multiply a string by a number with a decimal place, are there any ways around this? If nobody can answer the question please tell me how I could carry this out, thanks.

Comment: Friendly note: I'm also a computer science student at GCSE. Be careful with asking questions like this- the work must be your own overall. Specific questions like this are OK, as long as you cite the code that you take and show your understanding by commenting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use multiplying here, use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) together with iterating over the string:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> word = cycle('gcse')
>>> message = 'Hello, my name is Jake'
>>> ''.join([next(word) for c in message])
'gcsegcsegcsegcsegcsegc'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I have desperately needed, I will be able to continue and finish my coursework thanks to you :) I will be careful with my code and make sure it is my own, I understand this now so I should be able to comment on every aspect of it, thanks!